# How do I "correctly" structure es module package exports in 2023?

Tags: javascript, typescript, architecture, es6-modules

## context

I am currently breaking out my MVP code into cleaner packages and am looking to build a solid structural foundation at my early stage. I am using pure ES Modules + import maps, and have successfully (FTMP) migrated with changes like using *.mts -> *.mjs, `import` statements resolving to actual files with extensions, etc., but I do not understand the "correct" export strategy to enable consumers to fall into the pit of success.

As I understand it there are two basic approaches:

1. Include `index.mts` files throughout the folder structure, e.g. `export * from ./some.file.i.have.to.remember.to.re-export.mjs`. This would give the option for consumers to either import from the bare package `import { Foo } from '@my-scope/my-lib'` or directly from the pathed file `import { Foo } from '@my-scope/my-lib/subfolder/non-index-file.mjs'`.
2. Do not re-export throughout and only allow imports from individual files.

## question

Are these the only two options I have? Are these "correct"? Is there an emerging standard for this, or is this more of a religious question? If so, then I apologize in advance, but I am looking for dynamics-based consequences of these kinds of decisions, e.g. if one way screws up or complicates import maps on down the road.

## currently

I am currently trying to export with method #1 with mixed results. Sometimes I end up consuming these with bare imports (which I like FTMP), and sometimes I have forgotten to include an index.mts re-export and end up importing from a specific file (because I'm a lazy consumer also).